# Pandas str.replace with regex doubles results?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Let's say I have this pandas Series:

```
$ python3 -c 'import pandas as pd; print(pd.Series(["1","2","3","4"]))'
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: object
```

I'd like to "wrap" the strings "1","2","3","4" so they are prefixed with "a" and suffixed with "b" -> that is, I want to get "a1b","a2b","a3b","a4b". So I try https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

```
$ python3 -c 'import pandas as pd; print(pd.Series(["1","2","3","4"]).str.replace("(.*)", r"a\1b", regex=True))'
0    a1bab
1    a2bab
2    a3bab
3    a4bab
dtype: object
```

So - I did get a "wrap" of "1" into "a1b" -> but then "ab" is repeated one more time?

(Trying this regex in regex101.com, I've noticed I get the same "ghost copies" of "ab" at end if the `g` flag is enabled; so maybe Pandas `.str.replace` somehow enables it? But then, default is `flags=0` for Pandas `.str.replace` as per docs ?!)

How can I get the entire contents of a column cell "wrapped" in only those characters that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `(.*)` to `(.+)`:

```
andrej@Andrej-PC:~/app$ python3 -c 'import pandas as pd; print(pd.Series(["1","2","3","4"]).str.replace("(.+)", r"a\1b", regex=True))'
0    a1b
1    a2b
2    a3b
3    a4b
dtype: object
```

Comment: Many thanks, accepting this answer as the approach is the exact same as in OP (with regex)

Comment: But why?  What do we need to change * to +?  * is greedy, but I would like to undstand why. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston `.*` means match any character `.` **zero** or more times. That means it matches the zero-length value at the end of the string (that's why you see `a1bab` in the output). With `.+` that means the character must match at least once.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Ah, yes.  I understand.   Thank you!  Hence, the greedy term when using *.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
s = pd.Series(range(1,5))
'a' + s.astype(str) + 'b'
```

Output:

```
0    a1b
1    a2b
2    a3b
3    a4b
dtype: object
```